# Custom HTML output for registered navigation

Tags: menus

Is it possible to strip out the title / url from a custom navigation as to create a new HTML structure?

I'm creating a very unique menu structure, based on the custom menu created by a user in WordPress, but `wp_nav_menu()` does not seem to output only the title / url into an array. I could most likely get the HTML output from `wp_nav_menu()` and run a regex to strip out the various elements I need, but this seems overkill if a method already exits?

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

The `wp_get_nav_menu_items()` function returns an indexed array of WP_Post objects.

Here is an example:

```
$menu_name = 'custom_menu_slug';
$menu_locations = get_nav_menu_locations()
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menu_locations[ $menu_name ] );

$menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id );

$menu_list = '<ul id="menu-' . $menu_name . '">';

foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
    $menu_list .= '<li><a href="' . $menu_item->url . '">' . $menu_item->title . '</a></li>';
}

$menu_list .= '</ul>';
```

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items

Comment: I tried that, but I couldn't get the output like you outline. I'll take another look at the code, thank you.